# How to join command of npm?

Tags: javascript, shell, npm

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "cpFile": cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/
}
```

and I run:

```
npm run cpFile fileName.js
```

I want it to execute

```
cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/fileName.js
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Change `"cpFile": cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/` to `"cpFile": "cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/"`?

Comment: Also, please explain what _"but it not work"_ means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define scripts for npm command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863971/how-to-define-scripts-for-npm-command)

Comment: Thanks, but it not work. I hope the “src/view/home/” are the same, and the "fileName" are variable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need quotes around your command

```
"scripts": {
   "cpFile": "cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/"
}
```

then if you [need to pass in args](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), you will need to use the args delimiter

```
> npm run cpFile -- fileName.js
>> cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/ "fileName.js"
```

*probably not what you want*

you can read about it here too:

```
> npm help run
```

**Edit**

you will probably need to pass in the whole path to get what you want.

```
"scripts": {
   "cpFile": "cp ../template/index.js "
}
```

Then:

```
> npm run cpFile -- /src/view/home/fileName.js
```

Comment: I know the original question is a unclear, but is there any way to make it run `cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/customFileNamePassedFromShell.js`? Without using a custom JS script, of course. I did a quick search, but couldn't find a way, yet.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to write "".  And i hope the “src/view/home/” are the same, and the "fileName" are variable.  By the way, I am still learning English, do not be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

The serialization of `JSON` doesn't work with `functions`, `RegEx` nor `error-objects`. In addition this is **not** a valide *JSON format* you have posted.

`JSON` starts and ends with a curly brace `{ }` and you will need quotes around most names and values you created, except numeric values and booleans.

```
{ "scripts": { "cpFile": "cp ../template/index.js /src/view/home/" } }
```

There is also no method to run JavaScript without having plugins installed, like most browsers do.

Maybe `curl` can help to execute the script.